# redirect 301 subdomains to users own urls in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect

I have a rails app that gives users a subdomain for their site.  Users can then point their own domain to this sub domain to make it look like their own site.

When i user enters a domain name into my app i need to redirect any future requests to there subdomain url on my app to their own domain, also passing the path eg   company_site.hosted_site.com/pages/about_us redirects to www.company_site.com/pages/about_us.

Does anyone know how to do this in rails 3 ?

I cant so it using apache rules as need to hit the database to get redirect url and also dont want to change the conf file per users/subdomain.

Anyone done this ?  ssems might be best done in rack middleware ?  any ideas?

thanks alot
Rick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way is to do this in a `before_filter` block for ApplicationController so that all actions are affected by it:

```
before_filter :redirect_to_custom_domain

def redirect_to_custom_domain
  if (customer = Customer.find_by_subdomain(request.host))
    if (customer.domain?)
      # Redirects to the customer's full domain
      redirect_to(customer.domain_url)

      # Returning false will halt additional processing for this request
      return false
    end
  end
end
```

Customer would be your record where you store the assigned `subdomain` and an optional custom `domain` that they will be redirected to if it is specified.

In your Customer record you might have something like this as a helper method:

```
def Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  def domain_url
    "http://#{domain}/"
  end
end
```